# JUint - How to construct a Test Object

Tags: junit

Our Test Framework is based on Junit 3.x.

I am trying check with the current framework if I can execute junit 4 test cases.

There are different ways to execute a test case in our framework from command line or UI, a TestServlet

1)By passing a Testsuite - Fully qualified name
2)By passing Testsuite ( Fully qualified name) and individual test case  (to execute one test case from a suite)..

I am trying to fit in Juint4 tests in our proprietary framework which is using joint 3.x)

I am stuck with one piece .

New test cases are in  Junit 4  and using  JUnit4TestAdapter .

Question : How can I construct a Test Object when I know the annotated junit 4 Method.

### code

```
Class suiteClass = ClassUtil.classForName(suiteName);

Object o = ClassUtil.newInstance(suiteClass);

//the suite name passed contains junit4 tests

if ( !(o instanceof TestSuite)&& isjunit4TestCase(o))
{

       // see if the method exists in the class

       Method method;

       try {
        method = suiteClass.getMethod(testName);
       } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
   Log.harness.debug("method: %s not found in %s",testName, nameToUse);
   return null;
 }

 Test m_test = null;

 if (method.isAnnotationPresent(org.junit.Test.class))
 {
    /*here I need to construct a Test Object  and stuck
   junit.framework.Test  need this object to be returned
   */

m_test = (Test)method;

return m_test;
 }
 else
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [`JUnit4TestAdapter.filter(Filter)`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/JUnit4TestAdapter.java#L79)? You then have your choice of writing your own Filter or using [`Filter.matchMethodDescription(Description)`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filter.java#L47). That matching description gets really easy when you use the [`createTestDescription(Class<?> testClass, String methodName)`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/Description.java#L85) static factory method.

Because JUnit4TestAdapter itself implements Test, you can just pass your filtered JUnit4TestAdapter directly to the method that needs a Test instance.
Instances should be easy to create just by passing in a JUnit4 test class itself to the JUnit4TestAdapter constructor.

(In fact, you can probably avoid some of the reflection you have in your answer, and hand it off to JUnit to do for you instead.)

Comment: @Sajeev, you're welcome! If you'd like, click the up button next to an answer's number (score) to mark an answer as helpful, and the checkmark next to the most helpful answer once one solves your problem. It helps the better answers rise to the top, and marks your question as solved. You can do so for all your questions at any time. Good luck with your project!